# ASP.NET Make a control invisible added from Markup

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, vb.net

We have this ASP.NET web application using VB.NET, VS 2010. In the Markup there is a img tag for displaying some picture.

Can we control it from VB Code to make it visible = false

Comment: Note, with all the answers below mentioning setting `visible = false`. This will cause the actual image tag not to be rendered to the page. That means you will not be able to interact with it client side. If you wish have client side interaction your best bet would be to add CSS style of `display:none` or better still a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<img src="" alt="Alternate Text" runat="server" id="im"/>
```

in vb:

```
im.Visible = False
```

Comment: oh! so simple i didnt know it.. thnks all Deepak Jameem

Answer (score 0):

With `ASP.NET` you can use `Visible="false"` for any *Control*. If you want to hide your control *programmatically* again you can use `Visible` property of your control such as; `imgControl.Visible = false;`

If your image control is not a `ASP.NET` control then you can use `style="display: none"` or `style="visibility: hidden"` for any HTML control.

Answer (score 0):

You can add runat="server" in your img tag.

```
<img runat="server" id="imgid" src="ff.jpg" />
```

And then write code in code behind to visible false and true

imgid.Visible = false;

Answer (score 0):

Try this..Set `runat="server"`  for the control..

```
<img runat="server" id="img1" src="abc.png" />
```

After that in code benhind..

```
img1.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Removing marked answer and mark another answer with no extra researches is a bad idea,Friend..